# add thousands separator in SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have to process queries like this:

```
SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50000000;
```

It would be easier to read the code if boundary values could be expressed differently, such as:

```
SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50 000 000;
SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 50M;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not without adding a lot to the processing overhead when the query is run.

Comment: Use the REPLACE function to get rid of the spaces. See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND REPLACE('50 000 000', ' ', '');
SELECT some_col FROM some_table WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND REPLACE('50M', 'M', '000000');
```